# How to remove yellow marked border from table?

Tags: html, css

I want to remove yellow marked border here I attached code. Can you please help me to remove this? I have tried to google it but didn't find any result.

CSS:

```
    .table2 , .table2 th , .table2 tr, .table2 td {
                                border: 1px solid black;
                                border-collapse: collapse;
                                padding: 5px;
                                width: 850px;
    .table2 th.code {width: 12%}
            .table2 th.title {width: 35%}
            .table2 th.cgpa {width: 5%}
            .table2 th.credit {width: 13%}
            .table2 th.teacher {width: 35%}
            .table1 table th, td, tr {
                                border: 1px solid white;
                                padding: 0px;                           
                            }
```

HTML:

```
                        <table class="table2">
                            <thead>
                                <th class="code">Subject Code</th>
                                <th class="title">Subject Title</th>
                                <th class="cgpa">CGPA</th>
                                <th class="credit">Credit Hours</th>
                                <th class="teacher">Course Teacher</th>

                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                /* there has other tables data*/
                                <tr>
                                    <td>MAT-324</td>
                                    <td>Statistics & Probability</td>
                                    <td>4.00</td>
                                    <td>3 Hours</td>
                                    <td>Mr. Wahid Polash</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="3"></td>                                   
                                    <td>Total</td>
                                    <td>15</td>
                                </tr>


                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

I want to remove yellow marked border:

[image]

Comment: So find the code that causes the yellow border and remove it.

Comment: Obviously, we will need to see your code in order to help. Why not edit it into the question?

Comment: I have added code

Comment: @Naim886 Nothing in that code is causing the yellow border. Have you tried with a different browser and/or computer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and give a vague answer to a vague question.

In your css:

```
table { 
  border: none;
}
```

I also recommend that you post your code, and your problem more specifically.

Comment: .table2 , .table2 th , .table2 tr, .table2 td {
       border: 1px solid black;
       border-collapse: collapse;
       padding: 5px;
       width: 850px;

Comment: Nothing in that code would give you a yellow border. There's either other code or a wonky browser extension.